issue in loading lazy images on Chrome
I set the loading lazy attribute to my images, but they do not load when users scroll down to them, meaning that users reach the images and see them, but Chrome does not load them.
<img loading="lazy" width="132" height="132" class="cursor-pointer" src="src to get image" alt="sample alt" title="sample title">

I set loading lazy on image elements, but chrome does not load them.

How can u prove that is not working? Only if u use an old version under 77 it will not, but otherwise it works. One possible problem that I see is that u don't setup dimensions properly. Add "px" and unit size:  width="132px" height="132px". For lazy it must know the size before loading.

"Use loading=lazy only for images outside the initial viewport. The browser can't lazy-load an image until it knows where the image should be on the page, which causes them to load more slowly." - https://web.dev/articles/browser-level-image-lazy-loading

I tested these ideas, but none of them worked for me.

Did you check whether the browser makes a request for the image? You can verify that in the dev tools. Does it work without loading="lazy"?

I have checked it, and it did not make a request to get images. @MoritzMahringer
